# Images not showing up in PageView with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a PageView to display tree images that can be scrolled horizontally. The PageView also includes the titles for each tree. However, while the titles are showing up correctly, the images are not being displayed on the screen.

I have a `TreeModel` class that contains `id`, `title`, and `path` of trees. I am using the path inside the AssetImage widget to display the images.

Here's the code for my TreeModel:

```dart
class TreeModel {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String path;

  TreeModel(this.id, this.title, this.path);
}

List<TreeModel> treeModelList = [
  TreeModel(1, 'Tree 1', 'images/tree_illust.png'),
  TreeModel(2, 'Tree 2', 'images/tree_illust2.png'),
  TreeModel(3, 'Tree 3', 'images/tree_illust3.png'),
  TreeModel(4, 'Tree 4', 'images/tree_illust4.png'),
];
```

And here's the code for my `TreeDesignPage`:

```dart
import 'package:app/models/tree_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TreeDesignPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TreeDesignPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TreeDesignPage> createState() => _TreeDesignPageState();
}

class _TreeDesignPageState extends State<TreeDesignPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/landscape1.jpg'), // the background image
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: treeModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Clicked ${treeModelList[index].id}!");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(treeModelList[index].path), // PROBLEM HERE?
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 113.7,
                  top: 70,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 184,
                    child: Text(
                      treeModelList[index].title,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, despite using the correct `AssetImage` path, the images are not showing up on the screen.

Here's the file structure:

```
- lib/
  - models/
    - tree_model.dart
  - tree_design_page.dart
- images/
  - landscape1.jpg
  - tree_illust.png
  - tree_illust2.png
  - tree_illust3.png
  - tree_illust4.png
- pubspec.yaml
```

I have included the relevant portion of my `pubspec.yaml` file to ensure the assets are correctly configured.

Could someone kindly review my code and help me identify the issue that's causing the images not to show up in the `PageView`? Any insights or suggestions to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: There could be anything going on. Can you share your console output? also, please fix up your code structure, that would help you. Like, in pubspec.yaml you don't need to put every image. it will work fine with ```- directory_your_image_is_in/```. Aso if you are using the model for trees, use list.generate with it. And in tree_design_page.dart only share the relatable code, like pageview.builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have pass String in your Assets Image:**

You need to pass only the path not the path as string. You should use `treeModelList[index].path` instead of the string literal `"treeModelList[index].path"`.

**Solution Code:**

```
class TreeDesignPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TreeDesignPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TreeDesignPage> createState() => _TreeDesignPageState();
}

class _TreeDesignPageState extends State<TreeDesignPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/landscape1.jpg'), // The background image
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: treeModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Clicked ${treeModelList[index].id}!");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(treeModelList[index].path), // Updated image path
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 113.7,
                  top: 70,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 184,
                    child: Text(
                      treeModelList[index].title,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Now you will show the image.**

If image is not showing. Make sure that you have added `assets/images` on your `pubspec.ymal` file.

Comment: Man... how could I have missed that... Thanks for the help! It immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```dart
image: AssetImage("treeModelList[index].path"),
```

use this:

```dart
image: AssetImage(treeModelList[index].path.toString()),
```

> note: .toString() is optional and is there, just to ensure that type casting.